# Attach file button not showing in forms

Tags: 2007, attachments

I have a custom list (clicked together on the portal site, so no custom templates) in which attachments were disabled and afterwards re-enabled. The "Attach file" action menu item does however **not** re-appear on the New/Edit forms. No other customizations are done by the key-user since they have no access to SharePoint Designer or Visual Studio.
Is there a way to get this functionality working again?

Comment: Does this happen on editing all items that were created before and/or after attachments was re-enabled?

Comment: Every single one (created before and after). Note that all existing attachments were removed when disabling attachments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently picked up this project again (since it just had to be finished after all :)), and I found out what caused the attach file button to disappear when I recreated the list they left me from scratch.

If you try to use a calculated field with a reference to [Today] or [Me] you get a nasty error message which prevents you from making the column.

> Calculated columns cannot contain volatile functions like Today and Me

Now if you think you're smart, you can create a column Today, enter the formula in the calculated field and remove the column Today. Tadah, it *'works'*. Now go try and make a new item and the upload attachment button might be gone.

Answer (score 1):

I can't recreate this issue using a custom list, it seems to work fine for me or though I don't really understand what do you mean by clicked together ?

Comment: I mean it's created in SharePoint itself, not defined in a list definition and deployed in a feature. I wasn't able to reproduce it myself with another list either.

Comment: Weird :s, How about resetting the page to site defenition? I know you said that hasn't been modified but is nothing to lose on trying. To do this go to site actions > site settings, under look and fill click Reset to site definition and type the full url for your page.

Answer (score 0):

make sure no web parts were added to the form pages using the toolpaneview=2 trick